# Mongodb query for 2 level grouping

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

Suppose I have documents that, among others, have these fields:

```js
{
    "class" : String,
    "type" : String,
    "name" : String,
}
```

For example, many like this:

```js
{
    "class": "class A",
    "type": "type 1",
    "Name": "ObjectA1"
}

{
    "class": "class A",
    "type": "type 2",
    "Name": "ObjectA2_1"
}

{
    "class": "class A",
    "type": "type 2",
    "Name": "ObjectA2_2"
}

{  
    "class": "class B ",
    "type": "type 3",
    "Name": "ObjectB3"
}
```

What I want is a query that returns me the following structure

```js
{
    "class A" : {
        "type 1" : ["ObjectA1"],
        "type 2" : ["ObjectA2_1", "ObjectA2_2"]
    },
    "class B" : {
        "type 3" : ["ObjectB3"]
    } 
}
```

I tried using aggregate with $group but could not do this. Any thoughts?

PS: I would like to do this on mongodb shell, not mongoose or something like this.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using the aggregation framework will be that you cannot specify an arbitrary key name for a property of an object. So reshaping using that would not be possible without being able to specify all of the possible key names.

So to get the result you would need to work something in JavaScript such as [**`mapReduce`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/):

First define a mapper:

```js
var mapper = function () {

  var key = this["class"];
  delete this._id;
  delete this["class"];

  emit( key, this );

};
```

Then a reducer:

```js
var reducer = function (key, values) {

  var reducedObj = {};

  values.forEach(function(value) {
    if ( !reducedObj.hasOwnProperty(value.type) )
      reducedObj[value.type] = [];

    reducedObj[value.type].push( value.Name );

  });

  return reducedObj;
};
```

And because you have ( in your sample at least ) possible items that will be emitted from the mapper with only 1 key value you will also need a finalize function:

```js
var finalize = function (key,value) {

    if ( value.hasOwnProperty("name") ) {
        value[value.type] = value.name;
        delete value.type;
        delete value.name;
    }

    return value;
};
```

Then you call the mapReduce function as follows:

```js
db.collection.mapReduce(
    mapper,
    reducer,
   { "out": { "inline": 1 }, "finalize": finalize }
)
```

And that gives the following output:

```js
    "results" : [
            {
                    "_id" : "class A",
                    "value" : {
                            "type 1" : [
                                    "ObjectA1"
                            ],
                            "type 2" : [
                                    "ObjectA2_1",
                                    "ObjectA2_2"
                            ]
                    }
            },
            {
                    "_id" : "class B ",
                    "value" : {
                            "type" : "type 3",
                            "Name" : "ObjectB3"
                    }
            }
    ],
```

While the result is formatted in a very mapReduce way, it is definitely much the same as your result.

But if you really did want to take that further, you can always do the following:

Define another mapper:

```js
var mapper2 = function () {
    emit( null, this );
};
```

And another reducer:

```js
var reducer2 = function (key,values) {

  reducedObj = {};

  values.forEach(function(value) {
    reducedObj[value._id] = value.value;
  });

  return reducedObj;

};
```

Then run the first mapReduce with the output to a new collection:

```js
db.collection.mapReduce(
    mapper,
    reducer,
   { "out": { "replace": "newcollection" }, "finalize": finalize }
)
```

Followed by a second mapReduce on the new collection:

```js
db.newcollection.mapReduce(
    mapper2,
    reducer2,
   { "out": { "inline": 1 } }
)
```

And there is your result:

```js
    "results" : [
            {
                    "_id" : null,
                    "value" : {
                            "class A" : {
                                    "type 1" : [
                                            "ObjectA1"
                                    ],
                                    "type 2" : [
                                            "ObjectA2_1",
                                            "ObjectA2_2"
                                    ]
                            },
                            "class B " : {
                                    "type" : "type 3",
                                    "Name" : "ObjectB3"
                            }
                    }
            }
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for what I needed. It's not the same but solves my problem.

```
db.myDb.aggregate(
{
    $group:{
        _id: {
            class_name : "$class", 
            type_name : "$name"
        }, 
        items: {
            $addToSet : "$name"
        }
    }
}, 
{
    $group:{
        _id : "$_id.class_name", 
        types : {
            $addToSet : {
                type : "$_id.type_name", 
                items : "$items"
            }
        }
    }
})
```

this gave me something like:

```
{
    _id : "class A",
    types: [
        {
            type: "type 1",
            items: ["ObjectA1"]
        },
        {
            type: "type 2",
            items: ["ObjectA2_1", "ObjectA2_2"]
        }
    ]
},
{
    _id : "class B",
    types: [
        {
            type: "type 3",
            items: ["ObjectB3"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Both code and example were written here so there may be typos.

So this is about it. I want to thank #Neil Lunn for his awesome answer and dedication.

Marcel